# Organizing bluetooth LE services

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm using bluetooth LE to stream some pressure sensor data, along with an inertial motion unit data.

The IMU sensors need self-calibration to provide useful data. Some example of the calibration is moving it in a 8-figure path, or lay it down still for about 1 second. The IMU provide data, along with the calibration level (uncalibrated -- partially calibrated -- totally calibrated).

I currently stream pressure sensor + IMU data through a single service. Where should I put the IMU calibration data? In a different service, or a different characteristic?

Ideally, I want to be able to check the calibration level, perform the self-calibration, and then will start recording real data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use one service and different characteristic.
Actually on Bluetooth SIG  there is are many similar BLE profiles which may same with your requests, you may refer them.
There was an ongoing profile named TPMS but not adopted yet.